# API Integration: IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: python, rest, fastapi, darknet, yolov4

I am trying to integrate my Yolov4 darknet customed trained model using fast api but am getting an IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable on console and Internal Server Error on Fastapi local server. Following is my code to run the API:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Load YOLO v4 model
model = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet("yolov4_test.cfg", "yolov4_train_final.weights")

from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from typing import List, Tuple

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/detect_objects")
async def detect_objects(image: UploadFile = File(...)) -> List[Tuple[str, Tuple[int, int, int, int]]]:
    # Read image file
    image_bytes = await image.read()
    nparr = np.frombuffer(image_bytes, np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    # Run YOLO v4 model on image
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255.0, (608, 608), swapRB=True, crop=False)
    model.setInput(blob)
    layer_names = model.getLayerNames()
    output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in model.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
    outputs = model.forward(output_layers)

    # Extract bounding boxes and class labels
    boxes = []
    for output in outputs:
        for detection in output:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.5:
                center_x = int(detection[0] * img.shape[1])
                center_y = int(detection[1] * img.shape[0])
                width = int(detection[2] * img.shape[1])
                height = int(detection[3] * img.shape[0])
                left = int(center_x - width / 2)
                top = int(center_y - height / 2)
                boxes.append((class_id, (left, top, width, height)))

    # Map class IDs to class labels
    classes = ["Gun"]
    results = []
    for box in boxes:
        class_label = classes[box[0]]
        bbox = box[1]
        results.append((class_label, bbox))
        
    return results
```

Following is the error i am getting in console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\raafeh\desktop\fyp\envfast\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py", line 428, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "c:\users\raafeh\desktop\fyp\envfast\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\raafeh\desktop\fyp\envfast\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 276, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\raafeh\desktop\fyp\envfast\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\raafeh\desktop\fyp\envfast\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "c:\users\raafeh\desktop\fyp\envfast\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "c:\users\raafeh\desktop\fyp\envfast\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "c:\users\raafeh\desktop\fyp\envfast\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "c:\users\raafeh\desktop\fyp\envfast\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "c:\users\raafeh\desktop\fyp\envfast\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\raafeh\desktop\fyp\envfast\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\raafeh\desktop\fyp\envfast\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\raafeh\desktop\fyp\envfast\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "c:\users\raafeh\desktop\fyp\envfast\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 237, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "c:\users\raafeh\desktop\fyp\envfast\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 163, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "C:\Users\Raafeh\Desktop\FYP\main.py", line 27, in detect_objects
    output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in model.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
  File "C:\Users\Raafeh\Desktop\FYP\main.py", line 27, in <listcomp>
    output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in model.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

I am trying get the bounding boxes and Label out as the server response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a quick search, this has nothing to do with FastAPI but rather is caused by trying to index a NumPy scalar, an integer or float for example.

A quick look at the code would suggest that the `i` on the following line is an integer, and that causes the error:

```
output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in model.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
```

Maybe replacing `layer_names[i[0] - 1]` with `layer_names[i - 1]` might solve this.

Comment: After replacing according to your suggestion now I am getting the following error:

 File "C:\Users\Raafeh\Desktop\FYP\main.py", line 25, in detect_objects
    outputs = model.forward(output_layers)
cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code

Comment: What do `model.getLayerNames()` and `model.getUnconnectedOutLayers()` return? What are their data types? And what is `model.forward()` expecting?

Comment: getLayerNames(): Get the name of all layers of the network.
getUnconnectedOutLayers(): Get the index of the output layers.
model.forward() is a method to get my predictions on the input image

Comment: Based on the documentation, `model.getUnconnectedOutLayers()` returns a list of `int`s, indexes of layers, and you can't index them as they are not indexable types, so that's where the original error came from.

Comment: So, your `output_layers` should be a list of layer names that you pass on to `model.forward()`. It has [four different function signatures](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d30/classcv_1_1dnn_1_1Net.html#a98ed94cb6ef7063d3697259566da310b). All of them, apart from the first one, seem to expect an array of arrays or a vector of vectors, so could that be where your error comes from?

Comment: Also, could you extract the code in the `detect_objects` route to a stand-alone script that you could test locally without FastAPI and with the same data, i.e. reading the file directly from the disk? This would be easier to debug, too.

Answer (score 0):

So my problem was solved by replacing layer_names[i[0] - 1] with layer_names[i - 1] but then I faced another error of

> cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code

This was an issue with the OpenCV version I used which was 4.7, I changed it to 4.6 and volaa! My api code was working .